# Meta keywords in Maven generated website

Tags: maven, keyword, meta

Is there any way to add a custom meta tag in a Maven generated web site ?

```
<meta name="keyword" content="keyword1, keyword2"/>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, you just [Inject some XML into the `<head>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html#Inject_xhtml_into_head)

e.g. in your `src/site/site.xml`

```
<project>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <head>
      <meta name="keyword" content="keyword1, keyword2" />
    </head>
    ...
  </body>
  ...
</project>
```